# Need help to calculate new columns using the previous row in this row's calculation in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have requirement to work on the below data and generate two new columns (Old_OH and New_OH) based on previous row values. Hope someone can help me with the SQL query to bring in the new columns.

Couple of things:

1. For each ITEM and STR_I combination i have multiple entries of
   DMND_Q by FULFILMENT.
2. To start with the first value of Old_OH will be the BOH and from second occurrence it will the previous value of New_OH
3. New_OH calculation is New OH = Old_OH - DMND_Q
4. Both Old_OH and New_OH are partition by ITEM and  STR_I ad ordered by EVNT_TS.

Data:

```
ORD_D       EVNT_TS     ITEM      STR_I FULFILLMENT DMND_Q  BOH  Old_OH   New_OH

11/24/2016  18:57:13    51150417    4   STORE         1      2    2        1
11/24/2016  17:48:12    51150417    4   SPU           1      2    1        0
11/24/2016  16:23:15    51150417    5   SPU           1      3    3        2
11/24/2016  20:12:44    51150417    48  STORE         1      3    3        2
11/24/2016  18:27:14    51150417    78  STORE         1      3    3        2
11/24/2016  22:59:35    51150417    78  STORE         1      3    2        1
11/24/2016  17:24:11    51150417    78  SPU           1      3    1        0
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Is `BOH` always the same value for each `ITEM/STR_I` combination or should it be the value from the 1st row?

Answer (score 0):

well the answer is 
BOH + DMND_Q
- Sum(DMND_Q)
  Over (PARTITION BY ITEM, STR_I
        ORDER BY ORD_D, EVNT_TS
        ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
AS Old_OH,
BOH
- Sum(DMND_Q)
  Over (PARTITION BY ITEM, STR_I
        ORDER BY ORD_D, EVNT_TS
        ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
 AS New_OH